# Java Deadlock detection on remote server

Tags: deadlock, jstack

I've  created a simple monitoring python program that checks remote servers over ssh 
using paramiko and fabric api, now I want to find out if a deadlock occurred in remote server's java program.

I know that I can do this locally by using

```
$JAVA_HOME/bin/jstack -F `pgrep java`|grep "Deadlock"
```

but how can I do this over ssh using python?